# Why does Hibernate map LocalDateTime to timestamp (MySQL) and how can I prevent it from doing so?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, java-time

1. I think it is known that the `timestamp` column type in MySQL is meant to store "moments" in time.
2. According to [LocalDateTime official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), this class is:

> A date-time without a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such
> as 2007-12-03T10:15:30. LocalDateTime is an immutable date-time object
> that represents a date-time, often viewed as
> year-month-day-hour-minute-second

and is commonly used to store **dates with time**, NOT "moments" in time (it doesn't store using UTC as reference like other "moment" data types like [Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html)).

**Then why does Hibernate map `LocalDateTime` fields to `timestamp` fields in the database?** As I understand it, they are meant for different things!

It's causing me problems where I want to store raw `LocalDateTime` values in my database, but Hibernate ruins this by internally converting all my database `datetime`s to "moments" first (specifically to [java.sql.Timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html))

**Is this a bug? A design flaw? Or am I in the wrong here?**

By the way, I have tried setting up my entities like this

```
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "my_date_time_field", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
    private LocalDateTime myDateTimeField = LocalDateTime.now();
```

and Hibernate still does some awkard conversion when fetching from the DB because it thinks I'm fetching a "moment" instead of a "local date/time" value (still uses `TimestampTypeDescriptor` internally, where it converts to `Timestamp` before doing anything else).

PD: I know it's standard to handle all dates/times in UTC. Because of client requirements, I cannot do this. They only want to see local dates and times in the DB, and never see them converted, even if they are on a different timezone. They have explicity told me they don't care about the concept of "moments" because their business does not function **AT ALL** like that (After weeks of explaining and arguing about this, I'm pretty sure they know what consequences that brings).

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) the `timestamp` type is: "The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC. ".  Do you mean the `time` type?

Comment: What precise problem is this causing? i.e. "I store X, and I get back Y instead of Z" (given particular client and server time zones)

Comment: Where I have used Hibernate (and also EJB) we have always defined out database tables explicitly and not left them to be created automagically.

Comment: I see no reason why Hibernate would do that. Which version are you using and which dialect?

Answer (score 3):

This is done because the JDBC drivers can only be expected to support `java.sql.Date`, `java.sql.Time` and `java.sql.Timestamp` types, and there is no standard mechanism for checking what types the driver supports for using `setObject` for the parameters. Even if the MySQL driver supports it, there is no way of knowing if any outdated middleware abstraction layer won't try to validate that parameter and reject it.

Therefore, to ensure maximum compatibility the `java.time.*` types are converted to the `java.sql.*` types, and the JDBC driver only gives you `java.time.*` types that you have to make some assumptions on how they are used internally.

This is not a design-flaw in Hibernate, it is their approach to an undefined behavior in the available standards. And even if mechanisms to address this are introduced in the JDBC standards, it would still be years before support propagates enough on all levels that they can make use of it.

Comment: Great answer, that totally makes sense. Do you know of any clean way to make it behave like I want to?

Comment: There was some property you could set in your configuration to set the timezone for Hibernate, but I don't know if that's exactly what you want. If that doesn't work, then all the ways are dirty.